# Why does the following Regex extractor of JMeter always returning the default value?

Tags: regex, jmeter, jmeter-plugins

Following the Response data for a request.

```
<li><a href="xyzw.do?ab=1111111111110&amp;method=abcde&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-T00O-U00U-PCDE-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550" target="_top">
                    Letter</a>
```

Following is my regex extractor values

```
reference name : val
regular expression : <li><a href="abcde.do?ab=(.+?)
Template : $1$
match : -1
default value : error
```

I want the value of **ab** to be extracted. In this case 1111111111110

I tried the following:

1. Changed `(.+?)` to `(.+)`, `(\d+)` etc.
2. Changed `-1` as `0`

Above attempts doesn't give any fruitful output. I always see 'error' assigned to 'val'

Additional info: There are several `<li></li>` blocks like this, but there is only one `<li></li>` block that has `xyzw.do` in it.

Comment: You trying extract `ab` from `<li><a href="xyzw.do?ab=1111111111110&amp;method=abcde&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-T00O-U00U-PCDE-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550" target="_top">
                    Letter</a>` ?

Comment: I want the value 1111111111110 to be extracted. This value changes for each user.

Comment: can you give another example ? will there be `?ab=` always before the value you want to extract ?

Comment: Sure. <li><a href="xyzw.do?ab=2763276324872&amp;method=abcde&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-ABCD-EFGH-IHJK-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550" target="_top">
                     Letter</a>    Yes. Always there will be ?ab= before the value I wanna extract.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML with regex is not the best idea: [Using regular expressions to parse HTML: why not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not)

In addition to HTML parsing troubles, this won't handle another order of parameters, eg: `xyzw.do?method=abcde&amp;ab=1111111111110&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-T00O-U00U-PCDE-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550` won't match. Trying to handle this without doing actual HTML parsing first will lead you to a never-ending pit of screen scraping despair.

---

Your regex `<li><a href="abcde.do?ab=(.+?)` has some special characters that need to be escaped: it is saying "e followed by any character", and it also saying the "o" is optional (so `abcde.doab=` would match, as would `abcdeXdab=` -- but a including a question mark would cause it to fail).

The `.+` also means it will match the remainder of the string. the `?` greedy modifier after the + is irrelevant since there's no following pattern to end matching.

Working regex: `<a href="xyzw\.do\?ab=(\d+)`

See https://regex101.com/r/qW1iF7/1

Comment: This one doesn't work either. I read somewhere online that JMeter uses Perl type regex. But I see you have chosen PHP in the link. Would that be causing any issue?

Comment: I chose Perl-compatible regex (PCRE). I know nothing about JMeter. Apparently it uses [OROMatcher](https://www.savarese.org/oro/docs/OROMatcher/Syntax.html#Perl5Expressions). You could try `[0-9]` instead of `\d` .. otherwise, follow the usual regex debug exercise: pare back the regex until it works (even if it's not what you want, eg just `[0-9]+`), then slowly build back up.

Comment: Hi, What would be regex like,if I want the value of href to be set for the variable val.  "xyzw.do?ab=1111111111110&amp;method=abcde&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-T00O-U00U-PCDE-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550"  Remember, there are several  other <li></li> button this one alone has "Letter" in it.

Answer (score 0):

This regex should work in this case,

```
\?ab=(\d+)
```

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dB9rI4/1)

It uses the concept of [group capture](http://regexone.com/lesson/11)

Comment: He's already using a capturing group; that's what the `1` refers to in the template expression (`$1$`).  The problem is that it isn't capturing anything.

Comment: Yeah. I tried to extract someother simple regex, but for that also it return the default value.

Comment: Hi, What would be regex like,if I want the value of href to be set for the variable val.  "xyzw.do?ab=1111111111110&amp;method=abcde&amp;maintab=D&_UID_=111Y-T00O-U00U-PCDE-ZA7C-QQ99-0I00-0550"  Remember, there are several  other <li></li> button this one alone has "Letter" in it.

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as follows:

- Reference name: `val`
- Regular Expression: `ab=(.+?)&`
- Template: `$1$`

You can use [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener for testing your regular expressions against the response:

[image: Regex Tester]

See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) guide for more details on getting to the bottom of any problems with test design or execution.